# ArgoCD rest API endpoint for adding GIT repo URL

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, argo

I am not able to figure out the ArgoCD rest API endpoint for registering GIT repo URL. We would like to do this using the API instead of doing `argocd repo add REPOURL [flags]`. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: you could also create the repo with kubernetes manifest https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/declarative-setup/#repositories

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developer-guide/api-docs/), you can get the API docs using the `/swagger-ui` endpoint of the ArgoCD server. You could of course also use the Kubernetes API instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the API swagger

https://cd.apps.argoproj.io/swagger-ui#operation/RepositoryService_CreateRepository